# crashes on one users 10.6.8 machine with unrecognized selector sent to class

Tags: cocoa, macos, xcode4, bluetooth, osx-snow-leopard

```
2011-07-30 18:59:33.545 TokenLock[481:903] +[IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70c18cf8
2011-07-30 18:59:33.546 TokenLock[481:903] An uncaught exception was raised
2011-07-30 18:59:33.547 TokenLock[481:903] +[IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70c18cf8
2011-07-30 18:59:33.548 TokenLock[481:903] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff70c18cf8'
```

Actual code:

```
BluetoothDeviceAddress addr;
IOBluetoothNSStringToDeviceAddress(selectedBTDeviceSerial, &addr);
actualBTDevice = [[IOBluetoothDevice alloc] init];
actualBTDevice = [IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:&addr];
```

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot, or have him reinstall the IOBluetooth system stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+[IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:]` was introduced in the Mac OS X v10.7 SDK. Earlier OS X versions provide `+[IOBluetoothDevice withAddress:]` instead. You should be able to do something like:

```
if ([[IOBluetoothDevice class] respondsToSelector:@selector(deviceWithAddress:)])
    actualBTDevice = [IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddress:&addr];
else
    actualBTDevice = [IOBluetoothDevice withAddress:&addr];
```

Also, you’re leaking the object you’re instantiating with

```
actualBTDevice = [[IOBluetoothDevice alloc] init];
```

since you’re immediately assigning another object to that variable.